# Where is screed.tex?

Tags: tex-core

In [TeX for the Impatient](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/impatient/book.pdf), Chapter 2, Page 9, it asks to try compiling `screed.tex`.

Where is `screed.tex` and why did the author not explain what it is?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Note that while the first question might be answerable here, the second is probably off-topic for this site.

Comment: The author just used that as an example of a filename.  Does it throughout the text when explaining how to compile of manage files.  As a side note screed means a long speech or piece of writing, typically one regarded as tedious.   You have a classic example of 'geek' humor.    All you need to do is create your own *.tex file and use that instead of screed.tex

Comment: See, e.g., http://www.thefreedictionary.com/screed (could've been explained in the text, however)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about a linguistic misunderstanding.

Comment: I think it's a perfectly reasonable question (after the edits) and should stay here for future visitors. The whole (google-search) internet was silent when I faced this question and it annoyed me to no end. Sooner or later others would ask this question too and they would at least have this page showing in google results. The second question is answered well by R. Schumacher and is definitely not off-topic since a TeX book is invoking a certain geek humor and the reader may not be familiar with it (all the more reason to keep this page as an explanation to what the author failed to explain).